# Multiple converters for a json response with retrofit

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I'm trying to create a dynamic response based converter

 using retrofit, As for now I have 2 different answers returning from the server - one represents a failure and one represent a valid response How can I try and parse two different objects using the same adapter\callabck?

Comment: You should probably provide the JSON :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it as a java bean if data are json data.
You can use Gson to parse it.

1 Add lib

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

2 Create Retrofit
    private Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

Just add a Gson converter.

For example,

```
// success
{"retcode":0,"result":{"vfwebqq":"xxxx"}}
// failed
{"retcode":100,"result":{}}
```

3 Create a bean to receive data.

```
public class Result {
    public String retcode;
    public Info result;

    public static class Info {
        public String vfwebqq;
    }
}
```

4 Then you can return a bean object in retrofit interface.

```
@GET("xxx")
Result getHome();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I'm not quite in what are you talking about and what exact issue you are facing. But the first thing that pops out of my head is just to provide custom [JsonDeserializer](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.0). It should look like smth like this :

```
public class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<CustomData>> {
    @Override
    public List<CustomData> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        List<CustomData> customDataSet = new ArrayList<>();
        Iterator<JsonElement> iterator = ((JsonObject) json).get("data").getAsJsonObject().get(
                "records").getAsJsonArray().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            JsonElement element = iterator.next();
            CustomData customData = ServiceGenerator.mGson.fromJson(element, CustomData.class);
            customDataSet.add(customData);
        }
        return customDataSet;
    }
}
```

That's just a custom parser class example which is applied to RetrofitBuilder just to make life easier(maybe).
Afterwards you need to :

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<CustomData>>() {
    }.getType();
    mGson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(listType, new CustomDeserializer()).create();
    builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(mGson))
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL);
    retrofit = builder.build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, i believe this site helps with your challenge:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-introduction-to-multiple-converters